# Get @Request req.user injected in controller method value in e2e test case by using jest in nest js

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

I want to verify the @Request injected into controller method in jest e2e testcase
E2E controller:

```
async create(@Request() req) {
    //some code
  }
```

E2E spec:

```
await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/api/protected')
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      .set(id, id)
      .expect(200);
```

here I want to check `req.user` value in nestjs

I've tried many things but no luck, is there a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

`req.user` is a non-standard field that is appended **most** of the time by `passport`, via the `@nestjs/passport` package and the `AuthGuard()`. You must make sure to bind the guard just as you do for your regular application if you use a global binding via `useGlobalGuards()`, and you must make sure to send valid credentials for sign in